# ERC721 safeTransferFrom() Arguments

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721

When you list an **NFT** for sale on one of the NFT Marketplaces (like say **OpenSea**, **Rarible**, **LooksRare**, etc.) and someone then buys your NFT, which party is calling the `safeTransferFrom()` function at that point to make the transferring of that NFT happen from you to the Buyer? Is it that ***Marketplace's*** smart-contract that's calling `safeTransferFrom()`, or is it the SELLER - meaning the current owner of the NFT that's calling it?

As a quick reminder, here's the method's signature  --> and note how `from` is the very first argument in it:

```
safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
```

I'm asking because I looked at some recent sale transactions on **Etherscan** and found the info there to be inconsistent - and also just plain confusing.

For starters, we don't even always see `safeTransferFrom()` being called. Sometimes its a function called `fulfillBasicOrder(tuple parameters)` that gets called (this is with an OpenSea sale transaction.)
Of course, I'm assuming they wrap `safeTransferFrom()` ***inside*** of their `fulfillBasicOrder()` function, but either way - who is `from` in this case?

**======================**

**UPDATE:**

I think a bit of clarification is needed - judging from the responses I got...

I was trying to understand who `from` is in `safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)`.

I knew that `from` is the owner of the token being transferred - but then who is actually doing the calling of this `safeTransferFrom()` function? Meaning where is that call coming ***from***?

So these two different ***"froms"*** confused me.

Then I realized that when we call `safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId)` it is ***NOT*** necessarily the case that the caller of this function is the `owner` of the token.
Actually, when it comes to NFT Marketplaces, it's probably ***never*** the case.

And if we ***did*** want to find out and examine where the call was coming ***from***, all we would have to do is use... `msg.sender`

That's it.

The `safeTransferFrom()` call is coming ***from*** `msg.sender`, and the token it's transferring is `from` it's owner - just as we would expect it to be.

End of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `from` is the address of the current owner of the NFT.

See:

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-blockchain-programming/9781839218262/5395c544-a6d1-420a-88f8-bb29cb847e08.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

In any case either direct call to `safeTransferFrom` or some other contracts functions that wraps safeTransferFrom. when safeTransferFrom of NFT contract is called, it's always called with.

```
from: seller's wallet
to: buyer's wallet
tokenId: NFT id we are talking about
```

Answer (score 1):

As much as I can tell from your query, you are trying to determine who calls the `safeTransferFrom` function when we purchase an NFT.
For educational purposes, I'm currently developing an NFT market place. According to the tutorial I'm using, the marketplace's smart contract calls the `safeTransferFrom` function of the NFT you are purchasing.
And that, in my opinion, is how openSea, binance and other services operate.

An illustration of how the smart contract for the marketplace calls the `safeTransferFrom`

```
IERC721(nftAddress).safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId);
```

```
from is always owner of nft
to is always buyer of nft
```